# tf.Session.run not executing as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm working on a tensorflow project, and I'm having a problem I don't know how to solve. I guess it is because I am not understanding properly how tensorflow runs.

The code I think is relevant to the problem is:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

network_model.define_structure()

input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, network_model.n_input_features])
nn_output = network_model.feedforward(input_data)
q_values = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([self.batch_size, network_model.n_classes], 0, 1))

# Configure number of cpus to be used by tf
exec_config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=self.n_cpus)

# Initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session(config=exec_config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Get input for the nn in a list
    prepared_state = self.get_prepared_states()

    sess.run(tf.assign(q_values, nn_output, validate_shape=False), feed_dict={input_data:prepared_state})
    q_values_obtained = q_values.eval()
    print(q_values_obtained)
```

The problem is that the output of the neural network (`q_values_obtained`) has a very weird behavior: even if the input is different, the output is the same (as if `sess.run` wasn't executing properly), and sometimes, the output changes for some iterations, but then it is fixed again.

Where is the problem?

In case it is needed, I add as well the functions in the Network_model.py class `network_model.define_structure()` and `network_model.feedforward()`, which declare the weights of the neural network and do the feedforward step, respectively.

```
def define_structure(self):
        """The structure of the neural network is defined. From the attributes of the class, the hidden layers
        are built.
        """

        for i in range(self.n_hidden_layers+1):
            if(i == 0):
                self.weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.n_input_features, self.n_neurons_layers[i]], stddev=3.0)))
                self.biases.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.n_neurons_layers[i]], stddev=3.0)))
            elif(i==self.n_hidden_layers):
                self.weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.n_neurons_layers[i-1], self.n_classes], stddev=3.0)))
                self.biases.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.n_classes], stddev=3.0)))
            else:
                self.weights.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.n_neurons_layers[i-1], self.n_neurons_layers[i]], stddev=3.0)))
                self.biases.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.n_neurons_layers[i]], stddev=3.0)))

        return (self.weights, self.biases)


def feedforward(self, input_data, activation_function="sigmoid"):
        """Does a feedforward with the data received as argument and
        returns the output
        """
        # (input_data * weights) + biases
        print("In network_model.feedforward")
        for i in range(self.n_hidden_layers):
            output = tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.cast(input_data, tf.float32), self.weights[i]), self.biases[i])
            output_data = tf.nn.sigmoid(output)
            input_data = output_data
        output = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_data, self.weights[self.n_hidden_layers]), self.biases[self.n_hidden_layers])
        return output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved it. The problem was in the feedforward function. In order to get the output of the neural network, I was using in each of the layers the sigmoid function as activation function.

```
output_data = tf.nn.sigmoid(output)
```

The output of this activation function is either 0 or 1. This is not necessarily a problem, but in my particular case, it was producing the same output. This happened because I only have four neurons in this layer, and, therefore, since the input is not so different between samples, it is very easy for the output to be repeated.

On the contrary, using rectified linear unit (ReLU) as activation function, the output of this function is 0 only if the input is less than 0, and the value itself if the input is greater than 0.

```
output_data = tf.nn.relu(output)
```

Changing this last line with the other, the output is never the same, even if the output is very similar, which is my case.

Anyway, I guess that using a more complex neural network with more hidden layers and with more neurons, there wouldn't be this problem, even if you use the sigmoid function.